# 2D occupancy grid of a Gazebo world

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to visualize a 2D occupancy grid in rviz for a gazebo world, with extracting and publishing each feature seperatley. For example for an empty gazebo world with just a box and a cylinder , i want to publish both the box and cylinder as OccupancyGrid messages using separate publishers.

The issue i'm running into is getting the data for each model , is the only way to do this by parsing the world file and manually getting the dimensions ? Does anyone know if there is a way to convert a gazebo world into a 2D occupancy grid ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392542/2d-occupancy-grid-of-a-gazebo-world/) by [kdenver](https://answers.ros.org/users/91306/kdenver/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-12-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that gazebo is a 3d wold. You need to define a scan hight to get the Occupancy Grid. You may try the Plugin https://github.com/marinaKollmitz/gazebo_ros_2Dmap_plugin

It does what you need.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2021-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1